# I'm trying to build a simple proxy with net package, but the upstream is not sending any data back when I don't use go routines

Tags: go, goroutine

I wrote this simple proxy server with `net` package, which I expected to proxy connections from a local server at 8001 to any incoming connections via 8000. When I go to the browser and try it, I get a refused to connect error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
    "log"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go proxy(conn)
    }

}

func proxy(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    upstream, err := net.Dial("tcp","localhost:8001")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }
    defer upstream.Close()

    io.Copy(upstream, conn)

    io.Copy(conn, upstream)
}
```

But if I change the following lines in the proxy function

```golang
    io.Copy(upstream, conn)

    io.Copy(conn, upstream)
```

to

```golang
go io.Copy(upstream, conn)
   io.Copy(conn, upstream)
```

then it works as expected. Shouldn't the `io.Copy(upstream, conn)` block the `io.Copy(conn, upstream)`? As per my understanding, the conn should be written only after upstream has responded back? And how does having a go routine for `io.Copy(upstream, conn)` part solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't io.Copy block?

Yes. ["Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs."](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy). Since this is a network connection, this means it returns after the client closes the connection. If and when the client closes the connection depends on the application protocol. In HTTP it may never happen, for instance.

> How does having a goroutine solve this?

Because then the second Copy can execute while the client is still connected, allowing the upstream to write its response. Without the goroutine nothing is reading from the upstream, so it is likely blocked on its write call.

The client (presumably) waits for a response, the proxy waits for the client to close the connection, and the upstream waits for the proxy to start reading the response: no one can make progress and you're in a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. I think the part where the client may not close the connection gave me the needed clarity. It makes sense not block the copy from upstream to the client by using a goroutine for the first part.